# Making a function using .replace() to remove multiple characters in a variable string?

Tags: javascript, string, function, loops, replace

The function accepts 3 inputs: (string (str), starting point in string (index), and how many characters to remove after that (count)).

```
function removeFromString(str, index, count) {
  let newStr = '';
  for (let i = index; i <= (index + count); i++) {
    newStr = str.replace(str[i], '');
  }
  return newStr;
}
```

It's returning outputs that may remove one character at most, but nothing more than that, which is not what I am trying to achieve.

What I want is a function that when called, will return a function without the characters specified from the index and count parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
newStr = str.replace(str[i], '')
```

you're always taking `str` as the base string to replace - which is the original input. You're never using the `newStr` except after the final iteration; all replacements made before then are lost.

Another problem is that `str.replace(str[i], '')` will replace the same character if it exists earlier in the string, rather than at the index you want.

Slice the string's indicies instead.

```js
const removeFromString = (str, index, count) => (
  str.slice(0, index + 1) + str.slice(index + count + 1)
);
console.log(removeFromString('123456', 2, 2));
```

Comment: Shouldn't that second example return `1236`?

Answer (score 1):

Is just a matter of use substring method from JS.

[Substring method definition from Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```js
    function removeFromString(str, index, count) {
       return str.substring(0, index) + str.substring(index+count);
    }
    console.log(removeFromString('fofonka', 2, 2));
```